# udev rules fail to run a script on addition of usb device

Tags: debian, ubuntu, udev, hot-plug

Here is a simple rule I created in `/etc/udev/rules.d/21-persistent-local.rules` for my Seagate 500 GB expansion drive which uses a USB interface on a Debian machine running inside a VM.

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="NA453QQS", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", HOTPLUG == 1, \
RUN+="/usr/local/bin/run.sh"
```

After saving this, I run I run `udevadm trigger`. Finally, I plug in my drive and run `udevadm monitor --env` to verify if expansion drive is correctly loaded which is indeed the case.

Now I define the rule that on the `add` action, `run.sh` should run. `run.sh` has nothing except two `sudo insmod foo.ko` and `sudo rmmod foo.ko`. But the script fails to run. Concretely, nothing is printed in `dmesg` against the script `run.sh`. The module I load in the kernel prints messages which should be visible when exiting and entering the kernel.

What can be the possible reason for this problem?

P.S.: In the above rules file, I used both of these against the `ATTRS{...}`

`ID_SERIAL=Seagate_Expansion_NA453QQS
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=NA453QQS`

Comment: Why are you attempting to use `sudo`?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it should be `ATTR` rather than `ATTRS`.

Comment: Try changing the `SUBSYSTEM` to `block`, not `usb`. This is common mistake. Also the right `DEVTYPE` may be `disk` not `usb_device`. You may also be interested how to narrow to usb, that will be `ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb"` :-) Cheers.